# Congruences (not mod ideals) and CRT in non-UFD (examples).

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Is there a version of Chinese Remainder Theorem for non-UFD?

Can someone give an example?

Say $n=ab=cd$ holds in the domain where each of $a,b,c,d$ are irreducibles and we know $m\bmod a$, $m\bmod b$ and $m\bmod c$, $\bmod d$.

So the queries are:

suppose we know $m\bmod a$, $m\bmod b$ and $m\bmod c$, $\bmod d$ can we get $m\bmod ab$, $m\bmod ac$ and $m\bmod bc$, $\bmod bd$, $m\bmod ad$ and $m\bmod cd$?

Can we also get $m\bmod abc$, $m\bmod abd$, $m\bmod acd$ and $m\bmod bcd$?

Can we also get $m\bmod abcd$?

Comment: What do you mean by mod in this context?

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_arbitrary_rings) implies it generalizes to arbitrary rings.

Comment: @Mark So my query is valid? (but the general CRT is for ideals).

Comment: The normal statement of the CRT isn't in terms of congruances, but in the following way.  If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, and $I = I_1I_2\dots I_n$ is a product of irreducible ideals, then there exists an isomorphism $R/I\cong R/I_1\times R/I_2\times\dots R/I_n$.

The wikipedia page refers to a generalization past commutative rings, but I'm less familiar with that.

Comment: @Mark so my query is not valid?

Comment: @AJ. I'm not trying to say it's valid or not valid, I'm just trying to mention how it's normally presented.  Someone else may have more to about this.

Comment: The domains satisfying CRT are known as Prüfer domians. They have many interesting characterizations, e.g. [see this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/145267/242) for $27$ characterizations.